# index.html file recreation

Tags: apache, localhost, ubuntu-14.04

If someone deleted index.html file and unable to test the local host then how can be recreate that file to test the local host

Comment: The following command will create an empty file: `echo >/var/www/html/index.html` - but if you want to put something specific in there we can't really guess what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your terminal ( Command line ).

type

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/index.html
```

When your are in there, type

```
  <h1>It Works!!</h1>
```

hit Ctrl+o, and exit the terminal.

Take your browser. Type in

```
 http://localhost/
```

Voila, you have your localhost back, alive.

Comment: can you briefly tell me that how i store my web application files i /var/www/html/projectname/ so that it can  be access in browser, I keep my files in /var/www/html/projectname/  but index.php file doestnot work

Comment: What is the output when you go to index.php in your browser ?

Comment: First question. 
1. Do you have PHP installed ? If not install PHP, and restart your Apache server.

2. If you have PHP installed, is there any code in the index.php ? If so, what is the code ?

Comment: Remove all the code from your PHP file ( Or make a new php file, call it test.php ) and add "<?php echo "Something"; ?> " to it. And go to your browser and navigate it to test.php .

Comment: Again not working for me.. :( can you suggest me some tutorial link , may be I committing some silly mistake, coz I am new to PHP..